# php modulo and print_r of the result?

Tags: php, modulo

i wanted to make my own quarter-final draw for the champion's league (tomorrow, friday 16 of march) : i've got 2 questions : first the modulo does not work : it shows "another match" after every entry in the array, whereas i wanted it to be written **every two matches** (every 2 entries)...

Second question : is there a better way to "print" the result? like a print_r without the index and where i could say "**add `\n`** after each entry" ?

```
<body>
<?php 

$array = array("real", "barça", "bayern",  "apoel",  "chelsea",  "milan",  "benfica",  "marseille" );

$new = array();
$incr = count($array);

while($incr>0){
    $random = rand(0, count($array));

    if (!in_array($array[$random], $new)){
        $new[] = $array[$random];
        if ( (count($new) % 2) ){
            $new[] = " -- another match : ";
        }
        $incr--;
    }   
}

print_r($new);


?>
<p>results</p>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo is working perfectly:

- The array starts empty.
- You add an element to it.
- The length is 1, so `1 % 2`, so `1`, so truthy, so you add `-- another match` to the array
- **So the length is now 2**
- Next iteration of the loop, you add another element to the array.
- The length is now 3, so `3 % 2`, so `1`, so truthy, so you add `-- another match`

And so on. Whatever it is you're trying to do, it's not what you told the server to do.

What you should probably do is something like this:

```
$array = Array(........);
while($a = array_shift($array)) {
    $random = rand(0,count($array)-1); // -1 is important!
    echo $a." vs. ".$array[$random]."<br />";
    unset($array[$random)];
    // no need to realign keys since array_shift already does that
}
```

Comment: thanks, interesting, why do you use unset? for the print_r, yes actually i can put basic html code in a variable, with `<br/>` it seems a good solution

Comment: hmm, and about the -1? array_shift changes `$array`, so `count($array)` is the number of elements in the array after the shift...isn't it?

Comment: Unsetting the array element ensures it's not picked again. And for the `-1`... Well, suppose you have `Array('a','b','c')`, the `count` is 3 but the last element is in position `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to [shuffle](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array then just [pop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) off each of the elements

```
$array = array("real", "barça", "bayern",  "apoel",  "chelsea",  "milan",  "benfica",  "marseille" );

shuffle($array);

while($a = array_pop($array)) {
    echo $a." vs. ".array_pop($array)." <br />";
}
```

**Sample output**:

```
apoel vs. real 
barça vs. milan 
marseille vs. bayern 
chelsea vs. benfica
```

Comment: @Paul That's a bit freaky.. looks like my prediction was correct!

Comment: haha, nice, can you create a function to find out the winner?

Answer (score 0):

The modulus is working exactly as you're telling it to.

(count($new) % 2) ){

```
when count($new) = 1, 1 % 2 = 1, = true
when count($new) = 2, 2 % 2 = 0, = false
when count($new) = 3, 3 % 2 = 1, = true
when count($new) = 4, 4 % 2 = 0, = false
when count($new) = 5, 5 % 2 = 1, = true
when count($new) = 6, 6 % 2 = 0, = false
```